# EOFError: EOF при чтении строки

Tags: python, python-3.x, eof

Задание с учебного сайта hyperskill. С кодом разобралась (работает на replit), но когда запускаю его на самом сайте, то пишет, что

Ошибка:

Отслеживание (последний вызов последний):
Файл "jailed_code", строка 5, в
__email = input ()
EOFError: EOF при чтении строки

При этом в конце задания есть такая приписка:

"Функция должна вернуться, True если все условия верны, и False в противном случае.
Вы НЕ ДОЛЖНЫ ОБРАБАТЫВАТЬ ВВОД или вызывать свою функцию, просто реализуйте ее."

Что, %#&?, значит "не должны обрабатывать ввод"?!?!?!

В первоначальном варианте мой код выглядел так:

```
import re
email = str(input())
print(bool(re.fullmatch(r"\S+@[^.\s]+(?:\.[^.\s]+)", email)))
```

Потом я решила добавить def:

```
import re
symbols = r"\S+@[^.\s]+(?:\.[^.\s]+)+"
def check_email(string):
    return (bool(re.fullmatch(symbols, string)))
string = str(input())
print(check_email(string))
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, я третий день с этой задачей сижу, уже всех на этом сайте задолбала!!!

Comment: Возможно, что должна быть определена только функция. Безо всяких обвязок кодом (типа _input()_ или _print()_) вокруг. И, собственно, без вызова функции. Видимо тестовая система сама её обнаружит, позовёт, и проанализирует значение, что она вернёт.

Comment: В общем, попробуйте скормить ей ваш код без последних двух строк.

Comment: @GrAnd ,  Вы - мой герой!!!!!!!!!!!! Лучи добра и благодарности :-* :--* :-*